# dragging new instance of movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop

What I want to do is the following:

I have an image of a tray of marbles, when I hold the mouse down on the tray, an instance of a marble is created at the mouse position. Is there a way to start dragging the marble instead of the tray without lifting the mouse up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use startDrag in MouseDown event
**edit:**
See this link [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag%28%29)

Comment: Ok, solved. It didn't occur to me that you don't necessarily have to drag the event.target. Thank you for helping!